# Is it common to find software jobs that offer part ownership in company

Tags: software-industry, bonus

Do many/any companies offer a percentage stake in their organisation as an incentive for software developers to work for them?

If yes, what sort of companies and job-roles is this more common in?

Comment: I'm sure they do? How did you expect would this be answered?

Comment: My expectation was a "yes" or "no" and then if yes, an explanation on the type of jobs this is more common in (higher tier jobs? Startups vs big companies), and how to find these sorts of jobs

Comment: Ah, perhaps add that to the original question? It will help to offer a more precise focus to the question, otherwise the original stands as just "Yes". without more context.

Comment: Sure Frank, will do

Comment: I'll let someone with more experience to answer the question. Hope my suggestion helped.

Comment: This is more of a question for google than for stackexchange. Look for job postings that mention stock options, that will help more than asking here.

Comment: It depends very much on the country. For example, this is very common in the United States. But it's very rare in Slovnia. Also, this benefit almost always has compensating risks, for example, this is much more common with startups than with established companies. Except for key hires, where it's pretty common in the US for companies of all sizes.

Answer (score 2):

> Do many/any companies offer a percentage stake in their organisation
>   as an incentive for software developers to work for them?

Lots of software companies in the US offer Stock Options or RSUs (Restricted Stock Units). Both are equity in the company.

Sometimes these are sign-on bonuses. Other times these are just deferred compensation. Often, they come with a vesting period attached as incentive to stick around.

> If yes, what sort of companies and job-roles is this more common in?

All sorts of companies in the US do this. Perhaps more startups than established companies, but some of both.

It's common for software developers and other software engineering workers. Some companies offer equity to everyone.